# tsocks and OpenSSH

Tags: linux, networking, socks-proxy

I try to use tsocks as a socks-wrapper for an OpenSSH socks5 tunnel:

Here's my tsocks.conf:

```
wishi@kage ~ % cat /etc/tsocks.conf
# This is the configuration for libtsocks (transparent socks)
# Lines beginning with # and blank lines are ignored
#
# This sample configuration shows the simplest (and most common) use of
# tsocks. This is a basic LAN, this machine can access anything on the 
# local ethernet (192.168.0.*) but anything else has to use the SOCKS version
# 4 server on the firewall. Further details can be found in the man pages,
# tsocks(8) and tsocks.conf(5) and a more complex example is presented in 
# tsocks.conf.complex.example

# We can access 192.168.0.* directly
local = 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0

# Otherwise we use the server

server = 192.168.0.1
# Server type defaults to 4 so we need to specify it as 5 for this one
server_type = 5
# The port defaults to 1080 but I've stated it here for clarity 
server_port = 5000
```

So:

```
ssh -D 5000 me@server
```

And on another terminal:

```
tsocks transgui
```

No networking for the transgui application. I wonder what the issue is.

Comment: If you have the environment variable set you wouldn't need `tsocks`. Something like `socks_proxy=socks://localhost:5000/` or with `SOCKS5_PROXY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `ssh` only listens for tunnel connections on the loopback interface – try changing your `server` to **`127.0.0.1` or `::1`**.

If you need to connect from outside, use either `ssh -g -D 5000` or `ssh -D "*:5000"`.

Comment: changed server in tsocks.conf to 127.0.0.1 and did -g -D 5000 and tsocks transgui. No effect. Still no connection.

Comment: Try giving `-v -v` in addition, see if it prints out anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use ssh -L instead of -D

it uses local ports instead of dynamic if i remeber correctly, gives you less headache.

ssh -L LOCAL_PORT:SERVER:SERVER_SOCKS_PORT SERVER

this way you can also access a proxy server *behind* a ssh proxy

Comment: Using Dynamic SSH too, one can access the proxy server behind ! Please edit your answer

Comment: @PutPeace with dinamic your ssh server IS a socks server. yes, you can reach another socks server like you can reach anything else. but unlike with local port forwarding, you now have a socks server talking to another socks server.